# scalaquery : Dynamic BatchInsert

Tags: scala, dsl, scalaquery

The FirstExample in [scalaquery-examples project](https://github.com/szeiger/scalaquery-examples) 
provides an example of batch insert with the following Syntax:

```
 Coffees.insertAll(
    ("Colombian", 101, 7.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast",49, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("Espresso",150, 9.99, 0, 0),
    ("Colombian_Decaf",101, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
  )
```

How is it possible to pass a dynamically constructed List of tuples in the InsertAll method given that for this example the function definition is:

```
def insertAll(values: (String, Int, Double, Int, Int)*)(implicit session: org.scalaquery.session.Session): Option[Int]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform your List to variable-length arguments like this:

```
insertAll(tuplesList.toSeq:_*)
```

Comment: Cool Thks! Works like a charm

Comment: +1 indeed, it works quite nicely on List of case class instances as well ;-)